# Bluemix Spring - Application must be listening on the right port

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, jhipster

I'm trying to deploy a Jhipster application (Spring Boot + AngularJS) to Bluemix Tomcat. However I always get this error:

```
Error restarting application: Start app timeout
```

TIP: The application must be listening on the right port. Instead of hard coding the port, use the `$PORT` environment variable.

The complete error on Bluemix console is:

```
App instance exited with guid 1c76324f-57fb-4a00-b203-499519b4367c payload: 

{
  "cc_partition"=>"default",  
  "droplet"=>"1c76324f-57fb-4a00-b203-499519b4367c",
  "version"=>"0103e173-b6d3-4daa-a291-b5792c16b69b",
  "instance"=>"0c09506c30764b6c921cabb9a55d9e45",
  "index"=>0,
  "reason"=>"CRASHED",
  "exit_status"=>255,
  "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout",
  "crash_timestamp"=>1479341938
}

Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
```

I've already tried to change the `application-dev.yml` config to

```
server:
    port: ${VCAP_APP_PORT}
```

Or

```
server:
    port: 80
```

However, I have not had any success. How can I pass the port variable to the Jhipster configuration?

Comment: How are you packaging the app? JAR or WAR? If you're using Spring Boot, it should _just work_.

Comment: The message that you're seeing may not necessarily indicate a problem with the port, that's just one common cause of the problem.  The more general error is `start app timeout`, which means the app didn't start up within the allotted time.  You might try `cf push -t 180` to give the app more time to start.  If that doesn't help, you should run `cf logs app` in one terminal, then `cf push` in the other.  Capture the full output of  `cf logs` from push to failure and post that here.  That will give more details on what's happening.

Comment: Did you try adding the ${VCAP_APP_PORT} to application.yml as well? Maybe it's not running in dev config?

Comment: @EngineerBetter I'm packaging WAR files and pushing the SNAPSHOT.war.original, without the container embedded.

Comment: @RamVennam Just in case I added the ${VCAP_APP_PORT} in both profiles

Comment: @DanielMikusa I edited the question adding the complete error: App instance exited with guid 1c76324f-57fb-4a00-b203-499519b4367c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"1c76324f-57fb-4a00-b203-499519b4367c", "version"=>"0103e173-b6d3-4daa-a291-b5792c16b69b", "instance"=>"0c09506c30764b6c921cabb9a55d9e45", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1479341938}

Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections

Comment: I'm not sure that's sufficient.  You need to get logs from the application as it's trying to start up.  Can you run `cf logs` while you try to start the app and see if it logs anything?